# Why is it so badly slow to pass variadic arguments?

Tags: performance, go, parameter-passing, variadic-functions, idioms

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    n := 1024
    dst1 := make([]byte, n)
    dst2 := make([]byte, 0, n)
    dst3 := make([]byte, 0, n)

    start := time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        dst1[i] = byte(i)
    }
    fmt.Println(uint64(time.Since(start).Microseconds()))

    start = time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        dst2 = append(dst2, dst1[i])
    }
    fmt.Println(uint64(time.Since(start).Microseconds()))

    start = time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        dst3 = append(dst3, dst1...)
    }
    fmt.Println(uint64(time.Since(start).Microseconds()))
}
```

The benchmark results:

```
2
2  
2711
```

**Why is it so badly slow to pass variadic arguments?**

Comment: This has nothing to do with variadic arguments. You should use the benchmarking from package testing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last for loop uses append to add the larger "dst3" slice to the "dst1" slice multiple times. It takes significantly more time because each iteration involves copying the entire "dst3" slice to the "dst1" slice.

Comment: Answer is correct, I only want to clarify some technical details. Memory is copied, not on every iteration. It is only moved when slice size reaches its capacity. https://go.dev/blog/slices